# why getting "Cant add script behavior AssemblyInfo.cs" in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add a script with my object in unity. But it seems "Cant add script behavior AssemblyInfo.cs. The script needs to derive from MonoBehavior".
How can I fix the problem please..

I have already checked the script and class name which are same already.Moreover I've copy and pasted the code in another file but it didn't fix.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

void Start()
{

}
void Update()
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your script is treated to be not belonging to the project. In Visual Studio you'll find that your script would be labelled as **Miscellaneous file**.

Follow this -->
Edit >> Preferences >> External Tools >> External Script Editor : *Select* " Visual Studio "

Answer (score 0):

This is typically caused when a script is created outside of the Unity project. If you created the script with visual studio, file explorer, or simply copy/pasting the file, it may not be included in the Unity project.

Rather than try to re-build the assembly, simply create a new "PlayerMovement.cs" script using the Unity editor (right-click > create script) and write your code in that file.

Comment: I've done this by right_click -> create -> c# script again. But don't fix the issue.I do this only by deleting the previous. I don't understand what "try to re-build the assembly" mean.I've tried several hours but can't fix. please help me.
@Erik

Comment: Do you currently have a script attached to your gameObject @rosudel

Comment: MonoBehavior not MonoBehaviour :D

Comment: No, I'm begginer in unity. And it is first time I am attaching. @ErikOverflow

Comment: I've tried by MonoBehavior. but not working. @phantasm

Answer (score 0):

It is a common issue and can be solved if you rename your c# script to PlayerMovement.cs and then build the solution again. No need to create a new script.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've gotten a special case for this error. No common solution worked or applied for me, but I was able to solve it in an unexpected way.

To make the story short, the problem was that the **path** of my project was **too large**. (like, above 250 chars long, approx)

So, you could try moving your project to some *short-pathed-place* like your desktop (or renaming folders to make the route shorter) and, after that, delete your old script and creating a new one. (That worked for me)

For more info about this problem and the solution, take a look at this question and its first comment:
[DirectoryNotFoundException for an existing file path on Unity startup](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/168959/directorynotfoundexception-for-an-existing-file-path-on-unity-startup)

Note that if you aren´t having ^ that error, this answer probably won´t help you. How to know if you have it? Check the console or just the bottom part of Unity when you open it to see if there is some error like that one.

I hope that helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have just deleted the script, created a new one, waited a few seconds, and linked it again - it is (as far as I am concerned) some problem with sync between Visual Studio and Unity.